# Why Deadlock isn't happening?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I am confusing with the behaviour of Deadlock.
If I write first `a.foo(b)` and then `t.start()` in constructor of Deadlock class,then deadlock doesn't occur but why?

```
class A {

    synchronized void foo(B b) {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name + " entered A.foo");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("A Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " trying to call B.last()");
        b.last();

    }

    synchronized void last() {
        System.out.println("Inside A.last");
    }
}

class B {


    synchronized void bar(A a) {

        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name + " entered B.bar");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("B Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println(name + " trying to call A.last()");
        a.last();
    }

    synchronized void last() {
        System.out.println("Inside B.last");
    }
}


public class Deadlock implements Runnable {

    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    Thread t;

    Deadlock() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("MainThread");
        t = new Thread(this, "RacingThread");
        a.foo(b);
        t.start();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Deadlock();
    }

    public void run() {
        b.bar(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think is happening here that would lead to a deadlock? This looks fine...

Comment: What is your std output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I write *first* `a.foo(b)` and *then* `t.start()` in constructor of `Deadlock` class, then deadlock doesn't occur but why?

This is because `t.start()` is not invoked until the call to `a.foo(b)` completes since the call to `a.foo(b)` is not *asynchronous*.

Comment: Thanks.I've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To produce a deadlock, you have to have two processes (`a` and `b`) and two locks (`x` and `y`). They must acquire locks in a sequence like that:

- `a` acquires `x`;
- `b` acquires `y`;
- `a` is waiting to acquire `y`;
- `b` is waiting to acquire `x`.

In your code, you have `synchronized` methods. They are acquiring locks associated with instances on which the methods run. That is, they never try to acquire *each other's* locks. This is why they just get serialized.

To produce a deadlock, you need to depend on other locks than the implicit locks of `synchronized` methods.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this program the first thread that is created is **'main thread'**, so if you call a.foo(b) before t.start(), the program will be executed serially by main thread. So under main thread until the execution stack of a.foo() -> b.foo() ends t.start() will not be executed i.e.,

> in simple way until the code at line 4 execution completes code at
>   line number 5 will not be executed

. And hence in the case of `a.foo(b);t.start;` deadlock is not possible. But in case of `t.start();a.foo(b);` the asynchronous execution will begin soon after the **'thread t.start()'** and hence it results in deadlock between 2 threads trying to access each others opposite locks.